# How do I add the jain SIP libraries in a java project and to the java class?

Tags: java, addition, sip, libraries, jain-sip

I have downloaded the jain sip libraries files from https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/
and I am testing a small sip application but I am getting the error "package javax.sip does not exist" while importing as:

```
import javax.sip.*
```

I have used netbeans and eclipse adding the libraries as a jar file and/or folder.

Comment: Make sure you are not adding the archive tar.gz instead of the jars. The jain-sip jars are inside the tar.gz and you should unzip/untar them before adding them in the classpath. https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/jain-sip-1.2.2385.tar.gz

Comment: Yes, that was it and also I was referring to a folder instead of a jar file. Thanks @Vladimir Ralev